# Convert html anchor tag to mvc action link

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have this basic anchor tag inhtml

```
<a href="signup.html" class="signup-button">CREER UN COMPTE</a>
```

how can i convert it to mvc action link along with the css class.

Comment: Do you mean `@Html.ActionLink("CREER UN COMPTE", "Action", "Controller", null, null, "signup-button", new { categoryid = "blah"}, null)`

Answer (score 2):

```
<ul>
     @foreach (var item in Model)
     {
     <li>                                   
     <a href='@Url.Action("Login",new{id=item.id})'>@item.post_name</a>
      </li>
       }
  </ul>
```

Comment: Html anchor tag can be used in place of @Html.ActionLink like above.

Answer (score 0):

Try this guy:

```
@Html.ActionLink("CREER UN COMPTE", "MyAction", "MyController", null, null, "MyAnchor", null, new {@class="signup-button"})
```

Reference to extension method here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460522.aspx

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
 this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
 string linkText,
 string actionName,
 string controllerName,
 string protocol,
 string hostName,
 string fragment,
 Object routeValues,
 Object htmlAttributes
)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Code to Convert :**

```
<a href="signup.html" class="signup-button">CREER UN COMPTE</a>
```

If I look at the above code, you have redirected to the simple html page **i.e signup.html** by using the anchor tag.

And if you want the same thing in mvc actionlink  , As per my knowledge , the same thing is not possible by using the mvc actionlink because if you look at the below overloads of action link at msdn .

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460522.aspx

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    string controllerName,
    string protocol,
    string hostName,
    string fragment,
    Object routeValues,
    Object htmlAttributes
)
```

It takes only the actionname and controller name for any redirection to happen.

**Alternative solution:**

If you changed that signup.html to the signup action by using the controller then you can easily call by using the below code.

```
@Html.ActionLink("CREER UN COMPTE", "signup", "AnyControllerName", protocol: null, hostName: null, fragment: "MyAnchor", routeValues: null, new {@class="signup-button"})
```

Correct me if am wrong and hope that above information was helpful.

Thanks

Karthik